# Using HttpWebRequest send json to php symfony2- how can i get json in php

Tags: c#, php

```
    Dictionary<string, string> data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(json);
        if (data["ReturnValue"].Equals("0"))
        {
            List<M_Ninushi> m_ninushis = new M_NINUSHI_DAO().GetList(data["LastUpdateDate"]);
            string data_m_ninushi = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(m_ninushis);
            string sentResponse = Util.FilterData(data_m_ninushi);
            Dictionary<string, string> dataResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(sentResponse);
            if (dataResponse["ReturnValue"].Equals("0"))
            {
                return 0;
            }
            else
            {
                return 1;
            }
        }
```

this  id my code in webservice use asp.net. I use HttpWebRequest send data to symfony2 api
FilterData

```
    XElement xdoc = XElement.Load(configFileName);
    var objStringConnection = xdoc.Descendants("URL").Select(e => new { filter_data =    e.Descendants("URL_FILTER_DATA").FirstOrDefault().Value }).SingleOrDefault();
    string urlAddress = objStringConnection.filter_data;
    System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (senderX, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => { return true; };
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(urlAddress);
    Dictionary<string, string> json = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    json.Add("M_Ninushi", data);
    byte[] dataSent = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(json.ToString());
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    //application/x-www-form-urlencoded
    request.ContentLength = dataSent.Length;
    Stream writer = request.GetRequestStream();

    writer.Write(dataSent, 0, dataSent.Length);
    writer.Close();

    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

    if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader readStream = null;
        if (response.CharacterSet == null)
            readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream);
        else
            readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.GetEncoding(response.CharacterSet));
        string dataResponse = readStream.ReadToEnd();
        response.Close();
        readStream.Close();
        return dataResponse;
    }
```

this  id my code in webservice use asp.net. I use HttpWebRequest send data to symfony2 api
I know how to send data but I don't know how to get data in symfony2 . someone help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### C# Code Corrections

First, we need to correct the `Content-Type` sent to the server hosting the Symfony2 application. The data you are sending is not in the proper format for `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. Change it to `application/json`.

Also, JSON data **MUST** be encoded in Unicode. In PHP, [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/json_decode) only supports UTF-8 encoded strings. Therefore you must use `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes` instead of `Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes`.

`Dictionary.toString()` does not return a JSON string. Use [`Json.NET`](http://james.newtonking.com/json).

#### Receiving JSON Data in Symfony2

In your `Controller`, you can use [`Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request::getContent()`](http://api.symfony.com/2.0/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Request.html#method_getContent) to retrieve the form content.

```
<?php
namespace Company\CodeExampleBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException;

class RestAPIController extends Controller
{
    public function doSomethingInterestingAction(Request $request)
    {
        if($request->headers->get('Content-Type') !== 'application/json') {
            throw $this->createBadRequestException();
        }

        $jsonData = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);

        if($jsonData === null) {
            throw $this->createBadRequestException();
        }

        // DO SOMETHING WITH $jsonData
    }

    protected function createBadRequestException()
    {
        return new HttpException(400, 'This endpoint expects JSON data in the POST body and requires Content-Type to be set to application/json.');
    }
}
```